# Oracle - Select row where desired column contains only one specific type of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I've two Table 
Table 1

```
    +--------+--------+
    |   LC   | STATUS |
    +--------+--------+
    | 010051 |    6   |
    +--------+--------+
    | 010071 |    2   |
    +--------+--------+
    | 010048 |    2   |
    +--------+--------+
    | 010113 |    2   |
    +--------+--------+
    | 010125 |    2   |
    +--------+--------+
```

Table 2

```
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    |   LC   |     BILL    | LAST_BILL | PAYMENT_BY | STATUS |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010125 | BILL/17/001 |     0     |      C     |    6   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010125 | BILL/17/002 |     0     |      I     |    1   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010125 | BILL/17/003 |     0     |      F     |    1   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010125 | BILL/17/004 |     0     |      C     |    6   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010113 | BILL/17/005 |     0     |      C     |    6   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010113 | BILL/17/006 |     0     |      I     |    1   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010048 | BILL/17/007 |     0     |      C     |    6   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | 010071 | BILL/17/008 |     0     |      C     |    6   |
    +--------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
```

Where I just want to get the LC whose PAYMENT_BY is 'C', but others who have 'C' value and other than 'C' value, I don't want to get this LC.

I've try following query, but I think there's have expert who can done it in better way or most tuning way.

```
    SELECT   LC
      FROM   (SELECT   T1.LC
                FROM   TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
               WHERE       T1.STATUS = 2
                       AND T1.LC = T2.LC
                       AND T2.PAYMENT_BY = 'C'
                       AND LAST_BILL = 0
                       AND T2.STATUS = 6
              MINUS
              SELECT   T1.LC
                FROM   TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
               WHERE       T1.STATUS = 2
                       AND T1.LC = T2.LC
                       AND T2.PAYMENT_BY = 'I'
                       AND LAST_BILL = 0)
```

Query/Expected Result:

```
    +--------+
    |   LC   |
    +--------+
    | 010048 |
    +--------+
    | 010071 |
    +--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t2.lc from table2 t2
where 
  t2.payment_by = 'C'
  and
  not exists (
    select lc from table2
    where lc = t2.lc and payment_by <> 'C'
  )
```

If you want all the columns of table2, then:

```
select t2.* from table2 t2
..........................
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.lc, 
       count(case when t.payment_by = 'C' THEN 1 else NULL end ) as count_c,
       count(case when t.payment_by <> 'C' THEN 1 else NULL end ) as count_not_c
  from table2 t
 group by t.lc 
 having count(case when t.payment_by <> 'C' THEN 1 else NULL end ) < 1
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dee9c8fb6fb62c8a65e6477931fc0df8)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think `group by` and `having` is the simplest query:

```
select t2.lc
from table2 t2
group by t2.lc
having min(t2.payment_by) = 'C' and max(t2.payment_by) = 'C';
```

This also has the advantage of returning each `lc` exactly once.